# Erase a range from a filtered table - Run-time error

Tags: excel, vba

I need to erase some stuff in a table. I first filter what I want to keep and then erase what is left.

I have a "Run-time error '1004':"
This operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet.

I don't really understand, I using the same method in another table and it work fine.

My table start in range A3.

I also have form control button beside the table. Can that be my problem ?

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query_from_Visual_FoxPro_Tables").Range. _
    AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="X", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Y"
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
```

Comment: I suspect you need to use `Rows.Entirerow.Delete`. Deleting rows from a filtered table doesn't work in VBA - at least using `Listrows().Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx). Since your table starts in A3 but the `.UsedRange` starts at A1, you are going to delete the header row.

You need to look at the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) of the [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247(v=office.11).aspx).

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .ListObjects("Table_Query_from_Visual_FoxPro_Tables")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="X", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Y"
        With .DataBodyRange
            .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4
    End With
End With
```